Having trouble in formatting the AI model's response
I'm having trouble in formatting the response its making spaces in between of names and the response looks ugly so i need help to find a better approach.
 const { value, done: readerDone } = await reader.read();
        done = readerDone;
  
        if (value) {
          let chunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
         chunk = chunk
         .replace(/0:/g, '')                // Remove the '0:' prefix
         .replace(/"/g, '')                 // Remove double quotes
         .replace(/d:\{.*?\}/g, '')         // Remove any extra metadata
         .replace(/\\n\\n/g, '\n\n')        // Replace escaped newlines with actual newlines
         .replace(/}\s*$/, '')               // Remove trailing curly bracket
         .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')               // Replace multiple spaces with a single space
       // Handle markdown-like formatting
       chunk = chunk
         .replace(/ \*\s*/g, '\n• ')         // Replace bullet points (e.g., "* text") with actual bullet points
         .replace(/^\s*\*\s+/gm, '• ')      // Ensure bullet points at the start of lines
         .replace(/\n{3,}/g, '\n\n');       // Ensure proper paragraph breaks

        aiMessageContent += chunk;

But the response looks like this
"Hello ! Welcome to the A IC Society at Mehr an University of Engineering and Technology ! I 'm excited to chat with you about our events ! We have a wide range of activities and programs organized throughout the year . Can you please tell me what type of events you 're interested in learning more about ? Are you looking for tech -related events , or perhaps something more recreational ?"

its making gaps in between Mehran, AIC and You're.
the unformatted response looks like
"0:"Hello" 0:"!" 0:" Welcome" 0:" to" 0:" the" 0:" A" 0:"IC" 0:" Society" 0:" at" 0:" Mehr" 0:"an" 0:" University" 0:" of" 0:" Engineering" 0:" and" 0:" Technology" 0:"!\n\n" 0:"I" 0:"'m" 0:" excited" 0:" to" 0:" chat" 0:" with" 0:" you" 0:" about" 0:" our" 0:" events" 0:"!" 0:" We" 0:" have" 0:" a" 0:" wide" 0:" range" 0:" of" 0:" activities" 0:" and" 0:" programs" 0:" organized" 0:" throughout" 0:" the" 0:" year" 0:"." 0:" Can" 0:" you" 0:" please" 0:" tell" 0:" me" 0:" what" 0:" type" 0:" of" 0:" events" 0:" you" 0:"'re" 0:" interested" 0:" in" 0:" learning" 0:" more" 0:" about" 0:"?" 0:" Are" 0:" you" 0:" looking" 0:" for" 0:" tech" 0:"-related" 0:" events" 0:"," 0:" or" 0:" perhaps" 0:" something" 0:" more" 0:" recreational" 0:"?" d:{"finishReason":"stop","usage":{"promptTokens":null,"completionTokens":null}}" 

how to fix this?

Can you provide more information? for example which AI model you're using.

If you ask me, you'd need to find the correct format and parse it appropriately (not with just a bunch of .replace). For example, at a first glance, removing " 0:" would solve the main problem you're describing (instead of replacing the 0: and " separately).

just by using .replace(/" 0:"/g, '') results in: "0:"Hello! Welcome to the AIC Society at Mehran University of Engineering and Technology!\n\nI'm excit<snip>ch-related events, or perhaps something more recreational?" d:{"finishReason":"stop","usage":{"promptTokens":null,"completionTokens":null}}"
To me that looks like some sort of broken JSON. You should figure out the original format, transform the string a bit and then parse the result with JSON.parse().

I'm using llama3-8b-8192
